# Can you cache JNIEnv?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Is it safe to cache a JNIEnv object across multiple JNI calls? For example, can I do something like

```
void foo(JNIEnv* env)
{
    static JNIEnv* cached;
    if( ! cached )
        cached = env;

    /* use cached */
}
```

Of course, the code I have in reality isn't anything this silly, but the above example does demonstrate the usage case well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, *but only within a single thread.* Your cache can't be as simple as the above unless you are sure, somehow, that your native code will only be called on a single thread. Otherwise you need to use thread-local storage to hold your JNIEnv references.

Comment: Indeed. I'm actually caching the JNIEnv in a struct, and that struct will only be used from the thread on which it was created.